# How to source just parent items in a select field on suitelet form (API 2.0)?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

i am creating a suitelet form that will generate a pdf in POST. I need a field in my suitelet form, in which list of parent items can be selected(e.g. 1001 not 1001: 210-XL)for filtering purposes and all the items (child items) related to it can be printed in the PDF. Can anyone tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add only Parent items in SELECT field on Suitelet.
You will need to add SELECT Field and then addSelectOption.

```
var select = form.addField({
    id: 'selectfield',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
    label: 'Select'
});

var itemSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "item",
    filters:
        [
            ["parent.isinactive", "is", "F"],
            "AND",
            ["formulatext: {parent}", "isnotempty", ""]
        ],
    columns:
        [
            search.createColumn({
                name: "parent",
                summary: "GROUP",
                label: "Parent"
            }),
            search.createColumn({
                name: "internalid",
                join: "parent",
                summary: "GROUP",
                label: "Internal ID"
            })
        ]
});

itemSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
    select.addSelectOption({
        value: result.getValue({
            name: "parent",
            summary: "GROUP",
            label: "Parent"
        }),
        text: result.getValue({
            name: "internalid",
            join: "parent",
            summary: "GROUP"
        })
    });

    return true;
});
```

I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking that the parent field is blank...?  Not sure which record you are working with though, so that may or may not help.